# Group By eloquent laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have all the matches ordered by start_date, but i want the date not to be shown always instead separate the teams by date like below:

```
$matches=Match::orderBy('start_date','desc')->get();
foreach($matches as $match)
{
      $match->team1;
      $match->team2;
      $match->start_date;
}
```

this gives:

```
Team1
Team2 
2016-9-28
Team3
Team4 
2016-9-28
Team5
Team6 
2016-9-28
...
```

Instead I want

```
2016-9-28 
Team1
Team2 
Team3
Team4
Team5
Team6
....

2016-9-29
Team1
Team2
Team3
....
```

group_by start_date may be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupBy` to group the resulting collection.

```
$matchGroups = Match::orderBy('start_date','desc')->get()->groupBy('start_date');
```

If `start_date` is a Carbon date you may try

```
$matchGroups = Match::orderBy('start_date','desc')->get()->groupBy(function($item) {
    return $item->start_date->format('Y-n-j');
});
```

And in your view

```
@foreach ($matchGroups as $startDate => $matches) {
    {{ $startDate }}

    @foreach ($matches as $match) {
        {{ $match->team1 }}
        {{ $match->team2 }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: $startDate is not giving date. Also `foreach ($matches as $match)` gives the error.

Comment: @Steve see the updated answer. `groupBy` should come after `get`

Answer (score 1):

hmm.. you can try

```
$matches =  Match::select(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(team) AS teammate'), 'start_date')
           ->groupBy('start_date');
           ->get()
           ->toArray();
```

toArray is optional and the result should be:

```
array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "start_date" => "2016-9-28"
      "teammate" => "Team1,Team2, Team3, Team4, Team5, Team6"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "start_date" => "2016-9-29"
      "teammate" => "Team1,Team2, Team3"
    ]
]
```

is this the result you seeking for ?